# duplicate rows occurring when using inner_join in r

Tags: r, inner-join

I am trying to use inner_join between 2 data frames but getting duplicate values after the join.

I tried to create 2 subsets from the original dataframe with only 2 records and then join them. But still getting duplicate values for each user_ids.

```
ab1<- subset(df.age.dlx,df.age.dlx$user_id=="9218960788394762284" | df.age.dlx$user_id == "9221471567096564493")
View(ab1)


ab2 <-subset(df.gender.dlx,df.gender.dlx$user_id=="9218960788394762284" | df.gender.dlx$user_id == "9221471567096564493")
View(ab2)

ab.join<-inner_join(xyz_df,xyz1_df,by="user_id")
View(ab.join)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Without a reprex data example, there may be some difficulties here but this should work:

```
library(tidyverse)

ab1 <- df.age.dlx %>%
  filter(user_id == "9218960788394762284" | user_id == "9221471567096564493")

ab2 <- df.gender.dlx %>%
  filter(user_id == "9218960788394762284" | user_id == "9221471567096564493")

ab_join <- merge(ab1, ab2, by = "user_id")
```

Depending on what you're looking to do with your full dataset you can see you pipe together the above.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking into it. I tried to use merge(ab1,ab2,by="user_id") and it seems to work. Not sure why it would give different results when using merge and inner_join.